# Display uploaded image with multer

Tags: node.js, image, upload, display, multer

I am new in NodeJS and I am working on a projet using express, ejs and [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) (handle multipart/form-data) in order to upload a picture (single >> profile picture). 
I have been trying to display the uploaded file (image) in a view 
without success. 
I have all the information regarding the uploaded file (req.file) but I can't do anything with it.

```
//route.js 
   app.post('/upload_picture', isLoggedIn, upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){
        res.render('image', {
              path: req.file.path
        });
      });



//image.ejs
<section id="upload">
    <img class="uploaded-image" src="<%= path %>" alt="Image name: <%= path %>"/>
  </section>
```

Could somebody help me please.

Best regards, 
Dona

Answer (score 1):

So here is the solution, it worked for me !

```
var storage        = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, PICTURE_FOLDER));
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    var filename = Date.now();
    switch (file.mimetype) {
      case 'image/png':
      filename = filename + ".png";
      break;
      case 'image/jpeg':
      filename = filename + ".jpeg";
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
    cb(null, filename);
  }
});
var upload       = multer({ storage: storage});

app.post('/upload_picture', isLoggedIn, upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){
    res.render('image', {
      path: req.file.path
    });
});
```

Best regards, 
Dona